# public ip of container instance not accessible

Tags: azure-container-instances

I created an azure container instance az container create with these flags:

```
--dns-name-label my-protocol-api-containerinstance --ports 80 --ip-address=public --os-type=windows
```

And after creating it, tried to hit the fqdn as well as the public ip. Both return 404 not found error.

Comment: Could you share the full deployment details? Have you tried running an exec command and aci logs to check inside the running container things are working okay?